# Ruby on Rails app working on c9.io, crashing on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, cloud9-ide

My Ruby on Rails app works fine in development on cloud9.  When I push to Heroku, the application crashes immediately.  'heroku logs' shows:

```
2015-03-15T17:11:11.909831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-03-15T17:11:16.291267+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 42991 -e production`
2015-03-15T17:11:20.262015+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2015-03-15T17:11:20.262090+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:42991
2015-03-15T17:11:20.264853+00:00 app[web.1]: Abort testing: Your Rails environment is running in production mode!
2015-03-15T17:11:20.264972+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-03-15T17:11:20.262130+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-03-15T17:11:20.262170+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-03-15T17:11:21.206693+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-03-15T17:11:21.193413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-03-15T17:11:22.003251+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=agile-plateau-9101.herokuapp.com request_id=2889a78c-9ccf-4583-ac2b-978683cab62e fwd="149.151.180.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-03-15T17:11:22.536224+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=agile-plateau-9101.herokuapp.com request_id=355eeb91-1fb6-410c-a169-3407d7c2af67 fwd="149.151.180.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I've tried using unicorn and puma, both with the .rb files Heroku provides, with no luck.  I can't even get a console to run on Heroku.  'heroku run rails console' in the IDE shows 'Running `rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.9870' then brings me back to the IDE console, rather than Heroku's.  The Heroku logs for the console command are:

```
2015-03-15T17:16:48.811613+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by msandford@gmail.com
2015-03-15T17:16:54.386969+00:00 heroku[run.9870]: Awaiting client
2015-03-15T17:16:54.550213+00:00 heroku[run.9870]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2015-03-15T17:16:54.772282+00:00 heroku[run.9870]: State changed from starting to up
2015-03-15T17:17:01.220393+00:00 heroku[run.9870]: State changed from up to complete
2015-03-15T17:17:01.207230+00:00 heroku[run.9870]: Process exited with status 1
```

Any suggestions on where to begin troubleshooting this?

Edit: I've set up an Ubuntu server on EC2, and I'm getting exactly the same thing when running in development and in production. I'm using pg for both. rails s -e development runs fine, rails s -e production crashes immediately, and nothing is logged (that I can find)

Comment: Did you try debugging your app by running production within Cloud9? Does that work ok?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue: I had to comment out "require 'rails/test_help'" in environment.rd then everything ran along nicely.